# Extending class with only private constructors

Tags: java, reflection

The problem is: I have a class with only private constructor available (and I cannot modify it's source code), and I need to extend it.

Since reflections allow us to create instances of such classes whenever we want (with getting constructors and calling for newInstance()), is there any way to create an instance of an extended version of such class (I mean, really any way, even if it is against OOP)?

I know, it is a bad practice, but looks like I have no choice: I need to intercept some calls to one class (it is a singleton, and it's not an interface realization, so dynamic proxies do not work here).

Minimal example (as requested):

```
public class Singleton {
static private Singleton instance;

private Singleton() {
}

public static Singleton getFactory() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new Singleton();
    return instance;
}

public void doWork(String arg) {
    System.out.println(arg);
}}
```

all I want to do is to construct my own wrapper (like this one)

```
class Extension extends Singleton {
@Override
public void doWork(String arg) {
    super.doWork("Processed: " + arg);
}}
```

and the inject it into Factory using reflection:

```
Singleton.class.getField("instance").set(null, new Extension());
```

But I do not see any way to construct such object cause its superclass's constructor is private. The question is "is that possible at all".

Comment: Do you need to extend it for testing purposes or for your production code?

Comment: It's production code: Global problem is interacting with Eclipse CDT plugin and intercepting all it's compiler calls (more likely, all exec()s, even that ones which are called from native code). There is no standard way to do this, and looks like the best solution would be overriding it's only weak spot: ProcessFactory.

Comment: So why don't you decompile the compiled class?!

Comment: Cause end-user will have a version of this class with private constructor, and i can't do anything with it.

Comment: there actually *is* a way to extend a class with only a private constructor but that can only be done by an inner class.

Comment: Can you post a minimal code example of the class you want to subclass and an example of what you want to do in the subclass. Basically a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution by @René Link was good enough, but not in my case: I wrote I'm hacking an Eclipse IDE plugin, and this means we're working under OSGi, and this means we cannot control the classpath resolving order (it will load our "hacked" class in our bundle, and vanilla victim class in another bundle, and it will do this with different classloaders, and then we would have problems with casting such objects one to another). Possibly OSGi has some tools to solve this problems, but I don't know it well enough, and also I found no info on this.

So we invented another solution. It is worse than previous one, but at least it works in our case (and so it's more flexible).

The solution is simple: [javaagent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html). It's a standard tool, which allows to manipulate bytecode at the time it is loaded. So the task was solved by using it and [java ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) library: the victim's bytecode was modified to make it's constructor public, the remaining was easy.

```
    public class MyAgent {
        public static void premain(String agentArguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
            instrumentation.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {

                @Override
                public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer)
                    throws IllegalClassFormatException {
                    if (className.equals("org/victim/PrivateClass")) { //name of class you want to modify
                        try {
                            ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
                            ClassNode cn = new ClassNode();
                            cr.accept(cn, 0);

                            for (Object methodInst : cn.methods) {
                                MethodNode method = (MethodNode) methodInst;
                                if (method.name.equals("<init>") && method.desc.equals("()V")) { //we get constructor with no arguments, you can filter whatever you want
                                    method.access &= ~Opcodes.ACC_PRIVATE;
                                    method.access |= Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC; //removed "private" flag, set "public" flag
                                }
                            }
                            ClassWriter result = new ClassWriter(0);
                            cn.accept(result);
                            return result.toByteArray();
                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                            return null; //or you can somehow log failure here
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Next this javaagent must be activated with JVM flag, and then everything just works: now you can have subclasses which can call super() constructor without any problem. Or this can blow your whole leg off.

Comment: I understand how javaagent allows you to change private constructors to public at runtime, but how do you manage to trick Java into thinking that a provide constructor is public during compilation? I don't see how javaagent can help during compilation.

Comment: @Andrei, sorry for a late answer.

Since this situation occurs when you have a class with a private constructor in a library, you can create a modified version of this library  - by taking an original library and replacing the class with private constructor with an artificially created class file where the constructor has the same signature but is actually public - and then use this modified library during compilation stage.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up with adding a step before the compilation (thankfully it's really easy in Gradle) that automatically instruments the original class and puts the instrumented class version into the compilation classpath prior to the original library.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible (**but a bad hack**) if

- you have the source code of the class with the private constructors or you can reconstitute it from bytecode
- the class is loaded by the application class loader
- you can modify the jvm's classpath

**You can than create a patch that is binary compatible with the original class.**

I will call the class you want to extend PrivateConstructorClass in the following section.

1. Take the source code of `PrivateConstructorClass` and copy it to a source file. The package and class name must not be changed.
2. Change the constructors of the `PrivateConstructorClass` from private to protected.
3. Re-compile the modified source file of `PrivateConstructorClass`.
4. Package the compiled class file into a jar archive. E.g. called "patch.jar"
5. Create a class that extends the first one and compile it against the class in the patch.jar
6. Change the jvm's classpath so that the patch.jar is the first entry in the classpath.

Now some example code that let you examine how it works:

Expect the following folder structure

```
+-- workspace
  +- private
  +- patch
  +- client
```

Create the `PrivateConstructor` class in the `private` folder

```
public class PrivateConstructor {


    private String test;

    private PrivateConstructor(String test){
        this.test = test;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return test;
    }
}
```

Open a command prompt in the `private` folder, compile and package it.

```
$ javac PrivateConstructor.java
$ jar cvf private.jar PrivateConstructor.class
```

Now create the patch file in the `patch` folder:

```
    public class PrivateConstructor {


    private String test;

    protected PrivateConstructor(String test){
        this.test = test;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return test;
    }
}
```

Compile and package it

```
$ javac PrivateConstructor.java
$ jar cvf patch.jar PrivateConstructor.class
```

Now comes the interresting part.

Create a class that extends the PrivateConstructor in the client folder.

```
public class ExtendedPrivateConstructor extends PrivateConstructor {


    public ExtendedPrivateConstructor(String test){
        super(test);
    }
}
```

and a main class to test it

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String str[])  {
       PrivateConstructor privateConstructor = new ExtendedPrivateConstructor("Gotcha");
       System.out.println(privateConstructor);
    }
}
```

Now compile the `client` folder's source files against the `patch.jar`

```
 $ javac -cp ..\patch\patch.jar ExtendedPrivateConstructor.java Main.java
```

and now run it with both jars on the classpath and see what happens.

If the `patch.jar` comes before the `private.jar` than the `PrivateConstructor` class is loaded from the `patch.jar,` because the application class loader is a `URLClassLoader`.

```
 $ java -cp .;..\patch\patch.jar;..\private\private.jar  Main // This works
 $ java -cp .;..\private\private.jar;..\patch\patch.jar  Main // This will fail
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  This clearly doesn't work with the newly posted code examples edited into the question above, but I will keep the answer here for future posterity should it help someone else.

---

One method available to you which may or may not work depending on your situation is to use the  [Delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).  For example:

```
public class PrivateClass {
    private PrivateClass instance = new PrivateClass();

    private PrivateClass() {/*You can't subclass me!*/

    public static PrivateClass getInstance() { return instance; }
    public void doSomething() {}
}

public class WrapperClass {
    private PrivateClass privateInstance = PrivateClass.getInstance();
    public void doSomething() {
         //your additional logic here
         privateInstance.doSomething();
    }
}
```

You now have a class, `WrapperClass`, which has the same API as PrivateClass but delegates all the functionality to PrivateClass (after doing some pre or post work itself).  Obviously, `WrapperClass` is not associated with the type heirarchy of `PrivateClass` but can be setup to do everything `PrivateClass` can.

Comment: Sorry, but this class won't be an extended version of target class. The global task is to fake an instance field in singleton (with reflection), and your solution won't work for this case because of IllegalArgumentException